# map.on('locationerror'.. don't run the script

Tags: leaflet, locate

Scripts run on locationfound but not on locationerror.
locationerror is true when the user don't accept to share his position, wright?

If the user give his agreement, alert('ok') is done.
If he don't give his agreement, alert('error') is not done.
Someone's knows why?

```
var map = L.map('map')

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 10});

map.on('locationfound', function() {
    alert('ok');
});

map.on('locationerror', function() {
    alert('error');
    map.setView(45.0681298, 7.6059589, 10);
});
```

Comment: Which browser do you test it with?

Comment: Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? The docs say _Note that, if your page doesn't use HTTPS, this method will fail in modern browsers (Chrome 50 and newer)._